# How to #include files in separate directories using different IDEs?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, include, codeblocks

I am working on a C++ project using Xcode on MacOS X, and am now starting to port it to Linux using the Code::Blocks IDE.

Many of my source files are in separate directories and I am having issues including them.

Here is an example of this issue:

```
folder1/foo.h

folder2/dog.h

foo.h includes dog.h with: `#include "dog.h"`
```

It works fine on Xcode if both files in the same project but if I try it in Code::Blocks it has an error finding it.

I can fix this issue in Code::Blocks by changing the code to use a relative include path such as:

`#include "../folder2/dog.h"`

Unfortunately doing this stops Xcode from being able to find the file.

How can I fix this issue so I can compile the same code in multiple IDEs?  I would like to avoid throwing all the source in the same folder. Should I use a preprocessor statement similar to:

```
#if XCODE
#include "dog.h"
#else
#include "../folder2/dog.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Go into Code::blocks options and set the include directories.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg once that is setup, should I able to include a file directly like #include "dog.h" ?

Comment: Yep. That is one of the main points of setting include directories.

Comment: @Dmitri It doesnt.. I think what it does is copy all the headers from the project into one directory and compiles form there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange your structure so that one project has only one common include directory:

```
/project/
        /src/*.cpp
        /include/*.hpp
                /folder1/dog.hpp
                /folder2/cat.hpp
```

Now say `#include <config.hpp>` and `#include <folder1/dog.hpp>` etc., and add to your compiler flags:

```
-I ${PROJECT_DIR}/include
```

Comment: What if you want the header files to live next to their corresponding source files?  What if the IDE doesn't have a `-I` setting?

Comment: @Oli any decent IDE will have some way to specify where to look for include header files. If not supported explicitly then just add it as extra compiler switches manually.

Comment: +1 for restructuring source files. That's usually how I do it and that's the convention followed by many open-source projects out there.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: If the IDE doesn't allow you to configure compiler flags on a per-project basis, I'd say it's time to change IDEs!

Comment: @Kerrek: Indeed.  But the OP seems to be asking if there's a way to do this that's independent of any particular IDE.

Answer (score 3):

How a given compiler/IDE locates dependencies is, unfortunately, entirely compiler/IDE-specific.  There is no way to arrange this in such a way that it will be honoured by all development environments.

I don't know Xcode or Codeblocks, but I'm sure there must be some project configuration that controls where they looks for #include files.

Comment: So you would recommend doing all folder includes, by setting up IDE specific include paths?

Comment: @Justin - Other IDEs also have the possibility to add the files to a project. In that case it works just like in Xcode. If not, you can probably add a list of include directories.